# "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'" SQL server error

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are currently moving away from an access based database for sales data to an SQL Server 11 based database. At the moment we import from two sources into the database using VBA but are moving to use Python. The two sources use different account codes and to solve this we map the secondary customer code (DGS code) to customer code using a customer table that has the two different codes specified in the customer record. This SQL statement used to update the sales data with the desired primary customer code in Access using VBA.

```
UPDATE SalesData 
INNER JOIN Customers ON SalesData.DGSCode = Customers.DGSCode 
SET SalesData.AccCode = [Customers].[CustomerCode] 
WHERE (((SalesData.AccCode) Is Null))
```

however when used with SQL server in Python it returns the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

I would appreciate any help with solving this. Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server "11" is now officially SQL Server **2012**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are executing syntax for `MySQL`. Here's for `SQL Server`

```
UPDATE SalesData 
SET    SalesData.AccCode = Customers.CustomerCode
FROM   SalesData 
       INNER JOIN Customers 
          ON SalesData.DGSCode = Customers.DGSCode
WHERE  SalesData.AccCode Is Null
```

Comment: I had looked for solutions and had seen similar syntaxes but couldn't quite get it to work. Thanks very much.